# Replace spaces in string with regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to replace all all spaces in string with one space. I'm trying this:

```
String src = "2.       Test Sentence with     spaces";
String out = src.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
System.out.println(out);
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
2.       Test Sentence with spaces
```

Spaces after dot were not replaced... Why?

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me too. Is this your real code?

Comment: Could you take a look at your program in your editor's hex mode - perhaps there are some strange Unicode codepoints where you think that there are just spaces?

Comment: So, in HEX mode there is "c2 a0 NO-BREAK SPACE" symbols... How can I replace ALL spaces? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with the Unicode category: **separator, space**, combined with whitespace:

```
String input = "\u0020\u00A0\u1680\u2000\u2001\t"; //etc. 17 characters
System.out.println(input.replaceAll("[\\p{Zs}\\s]+", " "));
```

**Output**

```
[1 space]
```

See [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Zs/list.htm) for the list of characters in category `Zs`.